# What is best for logging

Tags: performance, logging, umbraco

since Umbraco v6 decided to implement logging to a text file by default, I would like to ask you guys what kind of logging you use.

Do you log to a text file on a production website, or do you log to a database table? Or do you implement any other kind of logging?

And what are the performance implications of this?

Answer (score 1):

I do both type of logging file as well as DB on production environment, as I need to audit logs so need to have everything actual and saved.

I use nLog.
http://nlog-project.org/

Its robust, fast and good and have been using it in production environment from last year.
Its good and gives you logging at various levels.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use NLog.

At one time I investigated question about the best frameworks for logging and stopped on NLog.
I have already used it on different projects and it always show good results.

With NLog you can sent your logs to a different targets:
file, database, event log, console, email, nlogviewer and [so forth](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Targets).

You can set up all configuration on config files. It's very cool and useful. You can easily set up how and where you want to write your logs.

At your disposal is also Wrapper Targets (see datail in documentation). In my opinion the most useful target is AsyncWrapper (provides asynchronous, buffered execution of target writes). It will give you good performance.

There are also a lot of another cool featers.